# selectize как сравнить переменную с options

Tags: jquery, laravel

Нужно выбрать опцию, сравнив перед этим все эти опции с текстовой переменной, если текст совпадает с опцией, то установить эту опцию. Не получается реализовать данный функционал.
Я занимаюсь парсингом данных по госномеру, получаю марку и модель с сайта, и хочу вставить в select #model модель, которую получил с сайта, предварительно проверив, есть ли она в опциях.

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="model" class="form-label">Модель</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="model" name="model"
        Placeholder="Выберите модель">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
// скрипт для изменения опций в МОДЕЛЯХ ПРИ ВЫБОРЕ МАРКИ
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Инициализация selectize для элемента model
    var modelSelectize = $("#model").selectize({
        respect_word_boundaries: false,
    })[0].selectize;

    // Обработчик события изменения марки
    $('#mark').on('change', function() {
        var selectedMark = $(this).val();

        // Если выбрана марка, делаем AJAX-запрос для загрузки моделей
        if (selectedMark) {

            modelSelectize.clearOptions(); // очищаем опции моделей от другой марки

            $.ajax({
                url: '/get-models/' + selectedMark,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    // Очищаем текущие опции в списке моделей
                    // очищаем опции, чтобы не было выбранной СТАРОЙ модели в списке НОВЫХ моделей
                    modelSelectize.clearOptions();


                    // Добавляем опции моделей в список
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        modelSelectize.addOption({
                            value: value,
                            text: value
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Если марка не выбрана, очищаем опции моделей
            modelSelectize.clearOptions();
            modelSelectize.clearOptions();
            modelSelectize.addOption({
                value: 'null',
                text: 'Список пуст',
                disabled: true
            });

        }
    });


@if (isset($data['model']))
        var modelValue = "{{ $data['model'] }}"; 
        var found = false;

        // Перебираем опции
        for (var key in modelSelectize.options) {
            var option = modelSelectize.options[key];

            // Сравниваем значения (без учета регистра)
            if (option.value.toLowerCase() === modelValue.toLowerCase() || option.text.toLowerCase() ===
                modelValue.toLowerCase()) {
                modelSelectize.setValue(option.value);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    @endif
```